# Protect files in dir .htaccess and allow access to a particular controler/action

Tags: php, apache, security

How to protect files (documents, images..) that r being sold over internet. 
Is it possible to Deny access to all except a particular php file that lists those documents.
for instance www.mysite.com/list

dir tree:

```
+ myfiles
|
|--img1.jpg
|--doc.pdf

+ application
|-+controllers
  |-lister.php
```

Can i grant access to myfiles DIR only from **www.mysite.com/lister/showfiles** NOT showfiles.php

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess file is responsible for client access only.
you can't use .htaccess to block scripts from accessing files.
it is your script logic responsible for such control.

to block client access to the files in the `myfiles` directory, just place an .htaccess with this line iin that directory:

```
Deny From All
```

Answer (score 0):

To block all web access except for url's that start with "/lister/showfiles", you need to place this .htaccess in you're web root:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule !^lister/showfiles - [F]
```